# How to declare Magnitude type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, types, type-traits

Say I have a template class that has to work with general types T complex and real but I also need a real type that I can store the abs(T) in. How do I get the appropriate type and make a type definition?

I tried the following:

```
template < typename T>
class sth{
typedef std::invoke_result<*std::abs, Value>::type real_type;

real_type sth_else(T x)
    return std::abs(f(x));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to define in through result of expression, then it would be something like

```
using real_type = decltype (std::abs(std::declval<T>()));
```

`declval` would provide a proper argument of type T to function

Comment: Awesome Thank you very much!